# SQL 1064 Error with basic database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I am trying to produce this database, which has a few one to many relationships but it gives me this error every time I run it and I cant figure out what I have done wrong.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
            REFERENCES users(user_id)

            )' at line 7
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
            user_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            pass VARCHAR(50),
            first_name VARCHAR(255),
            last_name VARCHAR(255),
            dob VARCHAR(30),
            address VARCHAR(1024),
            phone int(11),
            lastlogin DATETIME,
            PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mailboxes(
            mailbox_id int(10),
            mailbox_name VARCHAR(50),
            mailbox_type VARCHAR(255),
            user_id VARCHAR(50),
            PRIMARY KEY (mailbox_id)
            FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
            REFERENCES users(user_id)

            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts(
                contact_id VARCHAR(50)AUTO_INCREMENT,
                email_address VARCHAR(50),
                first_name VARCHAR(255),
                last_name VARCHAR(255),
                dob VARCHAR(30),
                address VARCHAR(1024),
                user_id VARCHAR(50),
                PRIMARY KEY (contact_id), 
                FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                REFERENCES users(user_id)

                );      
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages(
                message_id VARCHAR(50) AUTO_INCREMENT,
                mailbox_id int(10),
                contact_id VARCHAR(50),
                user_id VARCHAR(50),
                fromto_email VARCHAR(50),
                date_recieved DATETIME,
                date_sent DATETIME,
                message_data VARCHAR(1024),
                message VARCHAR(10240),
                PRIMARY KEY (message_id), 
                FOREIGN KEY (mailbox_id)
                REFERENCES mailboxes(mailbox_id)
                FOREIGN KEY (contact_id)
                REFERENCES contacts(contact_id) 
                FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                REFERENCES users(user_id)

                );  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flags(
                message_id VARCHAR(50),
                read_r VARCHAR(10),
                replied VARCHAR(10),
                sent VARCHAR(10),
                draft VARCHAR(10),
                user_id VARCHAR(50),
                PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
                FOREIGN KEY(message_id)
                REFERENCES messages(message_id)
                FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                REFERENCES users(user_id)

                );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot multiple commas between defning keys. For instance here

```
PRIMARY KEY (message_id),   <--here 
FOREIGN KEY (mailbox_id) REFERENCES mailboxes(mailbox_id)
```

And your `contact_id` and `message_id` must be `int` instead of `varchar` since you want them to be auto-increment.

This is the complete script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
            user_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            pass VARCHAR(50),
            first_name VARCHAR(255),
            last_name VARCHAR(255),
            dob VARCHAR(30),
            address VARCHAR(1024),
            phone int(11),
            lastlogin DATETIME,
            PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mailboxes(
            mailbox_id int(10),
            mailbox_name VARCHAR(50),
            mailbox_type VARCHAR(255),
            user_id VARCHAR(50),
            PRIMARY KEY (mailbox_id),
            FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
            REFERENCES users(user_id)

            );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts(
                contact_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
                email_address VARCHAR(50),
                first_name VARCHAR(255),
                last_name VARCHAR(255),
                dob VARCHAR(30),
                address VARCHAR(1024),
                user_id VARCHAR(50),
                PRIMARY KEY (contact_id), 
                FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                REFERENCES users(user_id)

                );      
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages(
                message_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
                mailbox_id int(10),
                contact_id int,
                user_id VARCHAR(50),
                fromto_email VARCHAR(50),
                date_recieved DATETIME,
                date_sent DATETIME,
                message_data VARCHAR(1024),
                message VARCHAR(10240),
                PRIMARY KEY (message_id), 
                FOREIGN KEY (mailbox_id)
                REFERENCES mailboxes(mailbox_id),
                FOREIGN KEY (contact_id)
                REFERENCES contacts(contact_id) ,
                FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                REFERENCES users(user_id)

                );  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flags(
                message_id int,
                read_r VARCHAR(10),
                replied VARCHAR(10),
                sent VARCHAR(10),
                draft VARCHAR(10),
                user_id VARCHAR(50),
                PRIMARY KEY (message_id),
                FOREIGN KEY(message_id)
                REFERENCES messages(message_id),
                FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                REFERENCES users(user_id)

                );
```